# How to automate filling of several pdfs?

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Does anyone know a good way to generate an adaptive pdf? I am currently working on a project where I need to create a report where text and numbers are inserted into the text in a template. I, therefore, need the pdf to adapt to the length of these inputs. My initial thought was converting HTML to pdf, which works, it is just very time-consuming to write HTML for 14 pages. I have tried different ways to generate HTML, from canvas to adobe and different applications found online. Although this often looks beautiful in HTML, the HTML generated in this way does not convert to pdf without compromising the appearance of the report. At least not with my method of using wkhtmltopdf. Does anyone have any ideas on how to efficiently make a beautiful pdf report that adapts to the length of text input?
Thanks for any answers:)

Comment: What framework or language in which source code has to be written for pdf conversion?

Comment: I have used python with wkhtmltopdf so far, but very flexible if anything else would work better.